# Sitecore Link (Xslt) Question Mark Issue

Tags: html, xml, xslt, sitecore

I got some code in XSLT in my sitecore project which displays link:

```
<sc:link title="{sc:fld('MenuTooltip',.)}">
    <xsl:call-template name="DisplayTitle"/>
</sc:link>
```

This is working fine unless I got text with '?' on MenuTooltip Field in sitecore.

For example, if MenuTooltip got "Reference Centre" it's fine it generates below html

```
<a title="Reference Centre" href="/reference-centre">Reference Centre</a>
```

Perfect now the things get bad, If I got "Reference Centre?" in MenuToolTip it generates some thing like below

```
<a &haschildren="true" href="/reference-centre">Reference CentreReference Centre</a>
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you try to use encoded `&#63;` instead of `?`?

Comment: Yes, Maras is right. Deep down in the belly of how Sitecore will render this, the ? and & characters is going to cause you problems. You need to UrlEncode the field value before outputting it to sc:link

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes it's some thing related to Sitecore link rendering Problem. I found alternative in doing this. I currently have no right to post answer now. I will when i get permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be two issues either you have some custom code running on sc:Link. check the below configaration in web.config

in my case i have not had any custom code and i am using Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 130529).

So

I replaced sc:link with anchor tag:

```
<a href="{sc:path(.)}" title="{sc:fld('MenuTooltip',.)}">
    <xsl:call-template name="DisplayTitle"/>
</a>
```

Suggested by  -John west